# Create js Webpack config with react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I create and config the webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }

};
```

And in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development"
  }
```

But in console show me this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\marle\Desktop\mern-stack\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! mern-stack@1.0.0 webpack: `webpack --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-stack@1.0.0 webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marle\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-29T23_50_32_004Z-debug.log
```

My webpack version is 4.41.2 and webpack-cli 3.3.9

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `target: node` in the webpack config.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/